# annotation-configured mybatis DAO with null in Date parameter

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

**UPDATE:** the problem was wrong syntax in the if@test where references are not supposed to be enclosed in `#{}`; the following works: `<if test='dateFrom != null'>`

---

I have a DAO object with a select taking (among others) a `java.util.Date` argument:

```
@Results({...})
@Select("<script>SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... <if test='#{dateFrom} !=
 null'>AND date &gt; #{dateFrom}</if></script>")
List<Person> getPersons(@Param("dateFrom") java.util.Date date, ...);
```

When a null value is passed via this argument mybatis complains:

```
org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: 
Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='dateFrom', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #2 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. 
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

I have read several advices, some of them suggesting to set the type explicitly to jdbcType=TIMESTAMP, but given my DAO is configured via annotations... is there a place where I can do that?

I tried to change the references from `#{dateFrom}` to `#{dateFrom, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}` but mybatis does not like that a bit:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'TIMESTAMP' not found. Available parameters are [param7, param8, param5, param6, offset, param9, contextId, canSignOnly, param3, dateFrom, param4, param1, param2, originatedOnly, limit, dateTo, itemTypeMask, param10, statusIds, signedOnly]
```

The annotation `@Param` does not seem to be offering a way of defining the jdbcType either.

Comment: If you have time, please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993678/2565527